# Can't print string after reverse in C

Tags: c, malloc, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

I'm writing this function to return a char pointer of reversed string.

```
void * PreverseStr (char str[]) 
{
    int size = strlen (str);
    char *returnstr = (char *)malloc (size * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    { 
        *returnstr = str[i];
        returnstr ++;
    }
    returnstr = 0;
    returnstr -= size;

    return returnstr ;
}
```

To test this function I wrote a main function like this

```
int main()
{   
    char str[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    char *newstr = PreverseStr(str);
    printf("Reversed string using pointer: %s\n", newstr);

    free(newstr);

    return 0;
}
```

But it crashes before it could print out anything. I wonder what's wrong with my code. It would be much helpful if you can explain a fix to this.

Comment: `returnstr = 0;` is invalid.  You've basically set your pointer to null.

Comment: Try simply saving the original pointer, and then restoring it after you run the loop.  See https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/DesertedWorrisomeControlflowgraph#main.c.  Or, simply return the saved pointer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant to write `*returnstr = 0`. Nevertheless, 10 seconds in a debugger should make it extremely obvious what is happening.

Comment: @Useless the compiler does not return any warning and I don't know how to use a debugger yet. But the problem has been solved. Thnks all

Comment: The compiler isn't obliged to warn you about this, and it's never too soon to learn how to use a debugger!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the return type `void *` makes no sense. The return type should be `char *`. As the function creates a new string without changing the source string then the function parameter should have the qualifier `const`.

This memory allocation

```
char *returnstr = (char *)malloc (size * sizeof(char));
```

allocates not enough space tp store the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the source string.

You need to write at least

```
char *returnstr = (char *)malloc ( ( size + 1 ) * sizeof(char));
```

After the for loop the pointer `returnstr` points to beyond the allocated memory because it is increased within the loop

```
returnstr ++;
```

Moreover after this assignment

```
returnstr = 0;
```

it becomes a null pointer.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
char * reverse_copy( const char s[] ) 
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    char *p = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( p != NULL )
    {
        p += n;
        *p = '\0';

        while ( n-- )
        {
            *--p = *s++;
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse_copy( const char s[] )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    char *p = malloc( n + 1 );

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        p += n;
        *p = '\0';

        while (n--)
        {
            *--p = *s++;
        }
    }

    return p;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "Hello, World!";

    puts( s );

    char *p = reverse_copy( s );

    if (p) puts( p );

    free( p );
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello, World!
!dlroW ,olleH
```

Comment: Yes, I've made many mistakes. Thanks for pointing that out